# Dúvidas ao utilizar a função "rle"

Tags: r

Estou utilizando a função rle.

```
x = rnorm(10,0,1)
l = 1
teste = rle(x > l)

evento = teste$lengths[teste$values=="TRUE"]
```

Estou com dificuldades para extrair quais são os valores do meu vetor x, que tem teste$values=="TRUE". Ou seja, eu quero saber os valores e não as posição que eles se encontram.

OBS: Quero fazer isso, utilizando a função rle.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está em utilizar `"TRUE"`, que é uma string, ao invés de `TRUE`, que é um valor lógico. O correto, usando seu código, seria

```
evento = teste$lengths[teste$values==TRUE]
```

Mas na realidade, qualquer comparação do tipo `==TRUE` é redundante, pois se `x == TRUE` resultar em `TRUE`, o valor x já é `TRUE` e não é necessário fazer a comparação. Você pode simplesmente utilizar o seguinte:

```
evento = teste$lengths[teste$values]
```

Ou, caso queria evitar a repetição de `teste`:

```
with(teste, lengths[values])
```

Comment: Era mais ou menos isso que gostaria de saber! Porém consegui fazer o que eu queria. Mesmo assim, muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu queria fazer era isso:

```
x = rnorm(10,0,1)
limite = 1
teste = rle(x > limite)

evento = which(teste$values == TRUE)
acumulada_lengths= cumsum(teste$lengths) 
fim = acumulada_lengths[evento]

auxiliar = ifelse(evento>1, evento-1, 0)
inicio = acumulada_lengths[auxiliar] + 1
if (0 %in% auxiliar) inicio = c(1,inicio) else inicio = inicio

obs = x[inicio[1]:fim[1]]
```